# Workflow to send email when condition is met

Tags: workflow

I need to create a workflow which sends an email to a specific manager.  I created a WF with the following...
[image: test workflow]

What I need is for the WF to send an email only when all the documents have the column 'Run' set to yes or else don't send an email.  The issue I am having is that it only runs on a one item.  I need it to go through each item to verify that it meets the criteria before sending an email out.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a **site workflow** to loop through the documents in the list and check the "**Run**" field of each document; the problem is that site workflows can only be run manually. 


From you question I presume that you want an automatic process. In this scenario you can:

- create a SharePoint 2013 workflow on the list that starts when a document is uploaded or changed
- use the **call web service** action and SharePoint **REST APIs** to retrieve all documents in the library
- loop through the documents and check the **Run** field of each document.
- If all documents including the current document have **Run = Yes**, then you send the email.

I hope this helps. I may be able to give you more instructions on how to do this tomorrow if needed.

Comment: If you could tomorrow, that would be excellent.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Mihail, can you send me the instructions please?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is create a custom timer job. This will execute each time you want (like 15 minutes, 9:00 AM ... ). In this timer job, we will add condition to check all of the documents have "Yes" on Run column or not. If true we will send email to specific manager, if false we do nothing.

Comment: Which condition would I add to check all of the documents?  Is the one, I posted, incorrect?

Comment: Yes. I think we will check all of the documents have the "Run" column is Yes or No, if Yes we will send email to manager.